# Restricting some commands from user

Tags: c#, cmd

I'm currently working on a project that contains two seperate applications. You install the first one on a server and use the second one to run some commands like `ipconfig` or `ping` at the server from a pc. Then the server returns results to the pc when the command has terminated.

Everything seemed nice until I realised this: what if the user runs `telnet` or `notepad` or something like that, it would never closes itself. There will be no results to show, no termination of the command.

What would you do in a situation like this ?

Comment: Please don't use **annoying formatting**.

Comment: Haha i just tried to highlight important parts. Wont happen again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either assign a timeout for process to execute, say 30 sec, after that time terminate the process, or do a whitelist of processes that users can run.

Comment: Both 'commands i might run' list and 'commands i might want to avoid' list are too big.